# Html Report generation failed in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Displaying the following error while generating the HTML Report. Response.jtl looks like below. timestamp column exists in the jtl file and total number of columns is 16.

[Jtl Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMnwq.png)

An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :No column  found in sample metadata , check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties to add the missing column

Comment: timeStamp elapsed label responseCode responseMessage threadName dataType success failureMessage bytes sentBytes grpThreads allThreads Latency IdleTime Connect
1583136464855 1629 Home page 200 OK SNACKDashboard 1-5 text TRUE  1587 411 4 4 1623 0 1382
1583136464853 1634 Home page 200 OK SNACKDashboard 1-1 text TRUE  1587 411 4 4 1634 0 1380
1583136464852 1635 Home page 200 OK SNACKDashboard 1-4 text TRUE  1587 411 4 4 1627 0 1391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .jtl file seems to have default configuration (apart this `success` column where values should be in lowercase)

Default "saveservice" properties look like:

```
C:\apps\jmeter\bin>type jmeter.properties | find "saveservice"
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t
#jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl"?>
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=
#jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
#jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

If you executed your test on one JMeter instance and try to generate the dashboard on another JMeter instance you need to ensure that these "saveservice" properties 100% match, otherwise you will face issues.

So double check *jmeter.properties* and `user.properties` files on both JMeter instances and make sure that you have the same results file configuration, once done you should be able to generate the dashboard successfully.

References:

- [19.15 Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/)